# xterm - What configuration controls # of windows

Tags: xterm

I'm using a xterm session I inherited, but every time I start it, it opens 4 windows. I'd prefer to open 1 or 2 windows. does anyone know the command line argument that affects the number of windows that start up? I thought it was the XTerm*font1-4 configuration, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Would it be the in the startup command argoument I'm using or the .Xsession config file?

/usr/bin/xterm -ls -tn xterms -sb -display @d

Answer (score 0):

It's in your `.Xsession` (or `.xinitrc`) file.  xterm creates only one window.  If you have four windows, that's four times xterm was executed in the initialization script, e.g.,

```
xterm &
xterm &
xterm &
xterm
```